# Unable to connect to MongoDB server at Interrupted system call

Tags: php, mongodb, centos, kohana, task-queue

I'm running a Rackspace cloud server CentOs + apache2 + php 5.4 + pcntl module with a basic Kohana php framework with a mongoDb task module that forks children processes. I get the following error if I try to run more then 1 child task process at the same time:

`Unable to connect to MongoDB server at Interrupted system call`

According to the mongoDb task module author the issue is not related to code but perhaps the mongoDb driver or the server.

Does anyone know what the error means and/or what may be the cause?

Full error output:

> 0 /var/www/.../modules/mangodb/classes/mangodb.php(370):
> MangoDB->connect()
>
> 1 /var/www/.../modules/mangodb/classes/mangodb.php(173):
> MangoDB->_call('command', Array, Array)
>
> 2 /var/www/.../modules/mangotask/classes/model/queue/task.php(33):
> MangoDB->command(Array)
>
> 3 /var/www/.../modules/mangoQueue/classes/controller/daemon.php(232):
> Model_Queue_Task->get_next()
>
> 4 /var/www/.../modules/mangoQueue/classes/controller/daemon.php(111):
> Controller_Daemon->daemon()
>
> 5 [internal function]: Controller_Daemon->action_index()
>
> 6 /var/www/.../system/classes/kohana/request/client/internal.php(118):
> reflectionMethod->invoke(Object(Controller_Daemon))
>
> 7 /var/www/.../system/classes/kohana/request/client.php(64):
> Kohana_Request_Client_Internal->execute_request(Object(Request))
>
> 8 /var/www/.../system/classes/kohana/request.php(1138):
> Kohana_Request_Client->execute(Object(Request))
>
> 9 /var/www/.../index.php(109): Kohana_Request->execute()

Answer (score 0):

Driver version 1.2.12 definitely has issues with forking, but this is something that should be resolved in the forthcoming 1.3.0 release. In particular, [PHP-426](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP-426) is one of the later issues to address this problem, as it relocated connection selection from `MongoCursor` to `MongoCursor::doQuery()`, allowing the driver to operate correctly after a fork. I would keep an eye out for the next 1.3.0 pre-release (either beta3 or rc1), and certainly when the final 1.3.0 version is released via http://pecl.php.net/package/mongo.